Как выводить на сайте комментарии с обращением к автору родительского комментария
Я хочу выводить на сайте комментарии с обращением к автору родительского комментария. Так:
Анна, я согласен с Вашим мнением…
НО у меня почему-то не работает обработка формы вторичного комментария. Что я делаю не так?
В БД у меня таблица comments с полями:
idс – id комментария
idt – id темы, которая комментируется
idpvc – id родительского комментария
comms – текст комментария
dateC - дата
avtorC – автор комментария
Я сделала отдельные формы для первичного и вторичного комментария:

//Форма для ввода комментария

//Проверим, авторизован пользователь или нет

if (!empty($_SESSION['auth'])) {

//Если авторизван, выводим форму для написания комментария

echo '<p  style="color:#E095B2;font-size: 18px ">

<b>Добавить комментарий<b></p>';

?>

<div class="comms">

<form method='POST' action='obr_c.php'>

<input type="hidden" name="idt" value="<?= $idt?>"/>

Наберите здесь текст комментария:<br>

<textarea name='comms' cols='50' rows='5'></textarea></br>

<input type='submit' name='s5' value='Опубликовать комментарий'>

</form><br><br>

</div>

 

<?php

//вставляю форму вторичного комментария

?>    

         <div class="otvcomm">

<p  style="color: blue;font-size: 18px ">

<b>Добавить комментарий к комментарию<b></p>

<form method='POST' action='obr_vtc.php'>

<input type="hidden" name="idt" value="<?= $idt?>"/>

<input type="hidden" name="idpvc" value="<?= $idсR?>"/>

idpvc=<?= $idcR?><br>

Наберите здесь текст комментария:<br>

<textarea name='comms' cols='50' rows='5'></textarea></br>

<input type='submit' name='s6' value='Ответить на комментарий'>

</form><br>

</div>


Форма вторичного комментария открывается после нажатия кнопки «Ответить» в соответствующем комментарии:

//Обработка кнопки Ответить  

if (isset($_POST['o'])){

         //Достаю из формы значение родительского idc

         $idcR=$_POST['idc'];

//Проверяю, передано ли значение родительского idc

         echo'$idcR = '. $idcR;

         //Делаю видимой вторичную форму

echo '<style>.otvcomm{display: block;}</style>';

         }       


Файл обработки формы вторичного комментария obr_vtc.php:

<?php session_start();?>

<?php header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");?>

<?php include 'functions.php';?>

<?php mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4');?>

<?php

$id = $_SESSION['id'];// id вошедшего юзера

//Получаю текущую дату

$odate = date('Y-m-d  H:i');

//Получаю из БД логин автора вторичного комментария

$query1 = "SELECT login FROM avts WHERE id='$id'";

$res=mysqli_query($link, $query1);

$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

//Достаём значения из таблицы в БД

$avtorC=$row1['login']; // из БД

// выполняем обработку формы для комментария

if (empty($_POST['s6']) || empty($_POST['comms'])

|| empty($_POST['idpvc'])) {

    http_response_code(403);

    die();

}else{

//Если из формы получены значения

//Получаю из формы

$idt = $_POST['idt'];

$idpvc = $_POST['idpvc'];

$comms = sanitizeString($_POST['comms']);

 //Сохраняю данные в БД

//Вставляю значение + дату в таблицу comments в БД

$query = "INSERT INTO comments(idt,idpvc,comms,dateC, avtorC)

VALUES('$idt','$idpvc','$comms','$odate','$avtorC')";

$res=mysqli_query($link, $query);

}

//редирект

$redirect = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']:'redirect-form.html';

header("Location: $redirect");

exit();

?>


Новый вторичный комментарий в БД вставляется, но с $idpvc=0, а не с тем, который я передавала во вторичной форме. Хотя в проверке видно, что во вторичной форме передаётся правильный $idpvc.
В результате того, что $idpvc всегда =0, обращение в комментарий в следующем коде не вставляется:

//Вставляю текст

         echo '<div class="comments">';

         if ($row1['idpvc']==0){

         echo $row1["comms"] .

         '</div><br/>';

         }else{

         //Вывожу имя автора первичного комментария с idc=idpvc

         $query4 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT avtorC FROM

    comments WHERE idc='$idpvc'");

    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query4);

         //вставляю сначала обращение по нику и запятую

         //потом текст вторичного комментария c обращением

         echo $row4['avtorC'] . ', '

         . $row1["comms"] .     '</div><br/>';             

         }


Подскажите, пожалуйста, что в моём коде не так, или, возможно, Вы можете подсказать другой способ вставлять обращение к автору родительского комментария во вторичные комментарии

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Синдром принцессы, "ах обслужите меня, а я буду капризничать". адекватность восприятия реальности уровня "бог".
